# Webpack-merge not accessing common configuration variables

Tags: javascript, webpack, production-environment

As I understand, webpack-merge helps us break down our webpack.config file into more manageable chunks, adding configuration relevant to the environment.

> While we will separate the production and development specific bits
>   out, note that we'll still maintain a "common" configuration to keep
>   things DRY. In order to merge these configurations together, we'll use
>   a utility called webpack-merge. With the "common" configuration in
>   place, we won't have to duplicate code within the environment-specific
>   configurations. 
>   - *Webpack - production*

My code in my `webpack.prod.js` is like so:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
            'file-loader'
        ],
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules") //NEED TO ACCCESS PATH VARIABLE HERE
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

In my `webpack.common.js` is the variable `path` in which I thought `webpack.prod.js` has access to. I'm assuming it doesn't as I am presented with an error:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
```

***Question***

How do I access the common configuration? Have I misunderstood the concept of `webpack-merge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`webpack-merge` will take two js objects and merge them using `lodash` [mergeWith](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge/blob/master/src/index.js#L24). So basically its returning a object which contains properties of both objects.

It cant provide with you `path` variable or any other variable. You will need to implicitely import it in your `webpack.prod.js` file.

Comment: Ahhhh ok. I just thought when Webpack states that it prevents duplication of code, I thought it meant I wouldn't have to duplicate code. When you say import do you mean `require`?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by `You will need to implicitely import it in your webpack.prod.js file`? Do you have some code to share? Thanx